# Socket not sending to Client or Client not recieving

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server, objectinputstream

I have a Server class and a Client class which is run on an android device. Basically, I need to load the user's friends and their IP address. The user's friends are stored in an ArrayList. So the client must send the friend's name and the server will respond with an IP address if the friend is online or a "-1" if the friend is offline. The server has access to all the users and stores it in an Arraylist of my defined type. My problem is that the client doesn't receive the IP Address/"-1" from the server, so only one friend is checked as the server is waiting for a response. The Login of Client is done elsewhere and is working perfectly.
Server:

```
public class Server {
     private static final int port = 9001;
     private static final String IPAddr = "xxx.xxx.xx.10";
     ServerSocket server = null;
     ArrayList <Client> users = new ArrayList<Client>();


     public Server(){
         readUsers();

        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("connected server on port" + port);
            while(true){
                System.out.println("waiting for connection my ip add is "+ InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
                Socket clientsocket = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Connect to client:"+ clientsocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                ClientThread client = new ClientThread(clientsocket);
                client.start();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port");
        }
     }

     public void readUsers() {
         //read form user text file on start up 
         ReadFile reader = new ReadFile("users.txt");
        try{
         String[] data = reader.OpenFile();
         for (int i = 0 ; i<data.length; i++){
            String[] parts = data[i].split(" ");
            ArrayList<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();
             for(int j =2; j<parts.length; j++){
                 ips.add(parts[j]);
             }

             Client clnt = new Client(parts[0],parts[1], ips);
              users.add(clnt);
         }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Couldn't read in data");
        }

     }
     public void RegisterUser(){
         //append to user text if a new user registers
     }

//Thread     
    public class ClientThread extends Thread {
        private Socket sckt = null;
        private String purpose;
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutput;
        ObjectInputStream objectInput;

        public ClientThread(Socket sckt){
            super("ClientThread");
            this.sckt = sckt;

        }
        public void run(){
            try{
            objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(sckt.getOutputStream());
            objectOutput.flush();
            objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(sckt.getInputStream());
            purpose = objectInput.readUTF();
            if(purpose.contains("login")){
                LoginUser();
            }else {
                LoadClientIP();
            }
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Couldnt read purpose: "+ purpose);
            }
        }
        public void LoginUser(){
            try{
                String Username = objectInput.readUTF();
                String Password = objectInput.readUTF();
                int ClientIndex = isClient(Username);
                if (ClientIndex != -1){
                    if(users.get(ClientIndex).password.equals(Password)){
                        //password correct  -> send friends
                        users.get(ClientIndex).online = true;
                        users.get(ClientIndex).SetCurrentIP(sckt.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
                        objectOutput.writeUTF("correct");
                        System.out.println(Username + " is correct");
                        LoadClientFriends(Username, ClientIndex);

                        objectOutput.writeObject(users.get(ClientIndex).Friends);
                        System.out.println("Friends sent");
                    } else {
                        //password incorrect -> retry
                        objectOutput.writeUnshared("password");
                        System.out.println(Username + " has wrong password");

                    }
                } else {
                    //not a registered client 
                    objectOutput.writeUTF("wrong");
                    System.out.println(Username + " is not a client");
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Couldnt connect to Client socket");
            }
        }
        public void LoadClientIP(){
            try{

            int size = Integer.parseInt(objectInput.readUTF()); //keep track of the number of friends
            System.out.println("The size of friends:"+ size);

            for (int j =0; j<size; j++){
                String client  = objectInput.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Client: "+ client);
                int i = isClient(client);   //index of friend is user arraylist
                if (users.get(i).online == true){
                    String IP_add = users.get(i).IP.get(users.get(i).CurrentIP);
                    objectOutput.writeUTF(IP_add);
                    System.out.println("Client is at index i "+ i + " with IP "+ IP_add);
                }else {
                    objectOutput.writeUTF("-1");
                    System.out.println("Client is not online");
                }

            }
            System.out.println("out of while");
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println("Couldn't load IP");
            }
        }
    }
    public void LoadClientFriends(String name, int index){
        //upon a client signing in, server must load his friends contacts
         ReadFile reader = new ReadFile(name+".txt");
         try{
             String[] data = reader.OpenFile();

             for (int i = 0 ; i<data.length; i++){
                  users.get(index).Friends.add(data[i]);

             }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Couldn't read in friend data");
            }
    }
    public int isClient(String name){
        boolean isclient = false;
        int i =0;
        int index =-1;
        while((isclient == false) && (i<users.size())){
            if (name.equals(users.get(i).Username)){
                isclient = true;
                index = i;
            }else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Server svr = new Server();
    }
}
```

Client/Android:

```
 public class chat_screen extends ActionBarActivity {
     ArrayList<String> friends;
     ArrayList<String> onlineIP;
     ArrayList<String> onlineFriend;
     private static final int port = 9001;
     private static final String IPAddr = "xx.x.x.4";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_menu);
        friends = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Friends");

     Thread FriendThread = new Thread(Connect);
     FriendThread.start();
    }

    //Thread
   Runnable Connect = new Runnable()
   {
       public void run()
       {
        try {
            //Problems: getting stuck when reading in friends, only is able to send the first friend
            Socket connection = new Socket(IPAddr,port);

            ObjectOutputStream objectout = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            objectout.flush();
            ObjectInputStream objectin = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); 

            //send purpose
            objectout.writeUTF("load");
            objectout.flush();
            objectout.writeUTF(Integer.toString(friends.size()));
            objectout.flush();
            //send friends name to get IP
            for(int i =0; i<friends.size(); i++){
                objectout.writeUTF(friends.get(i));
                objectout.flush();
                String ip = objectin.readUTF(); //stuck on this line

                if ((ip.contains("-1"))== false){
                    onlineIP.add(ip);
                    onlineFriend.add(friends.get(i));
                }else {
                   //do nothing
                }
            }
            connection.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            finish();
        }
     }
    };
}
```

Comment: You should tell more. Why is there that `IPAddr` in the werver? It's ok that you dont use it in the server class. Where runs your server? PC/device? Where runs your client? Device/emulator? Is there a connection? Why does the srver wait when the client received a -1? You should tell more.

Comment: `So the client must send the friend's name` ?? What i see is that the client sends a whole array list of friends.

Comment: `objectout.writeUTF("load");`. We do not see this "load" back in the server. You should do that to make your code better readable.

Comment: `objectOutput.writeUTF(IP_add);` You could add a flush() there. And after -1 too.

Comment: `objectout.writeUTF(Integer.toString(friends.size()));` I wonder what is really written for this integer. Is the value of size received by the server ok?

Comment: @greenapps The server is run on my computer and the client is run on my phone, the Client must send a friend's name and the server will respond with that friends ip address if they are online. The keyword "load" is sent from the client so the server knows to go to the LoadClientIP() method in the server thread. Friends.size() does send over the number of friends in the Friends Arraylist.

Comment: You did not understand the comments i gave. Please re read and give to the point answers.